# MSSQL ODBC refusing valid TINYINT values (Numeric value out of range)

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to insert into a TINYINT column which according to [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) should take numbers between 0-255. Unfortunately it only takes 0-127. If I try to insert 128 or higher it complains:

```
[22003] (native 0): [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range
```

The data is bound as `SQL_C_SBIGINT` because it's a general code meant to take all integers, but I think that that shouldn't matter because for numbers 0-127 it works correctly. There's also an option to send it as a `SQL_C_CHAR` string, but that returns the same error.

Anyone knows where the problem might lie?

Comment: Have you tried `SQL_TINYINT`?

Comment: I wonder if it is an unsigned/signed thing? Is the value within your code an unsigned int?

Comment: Nope. I'm writing an ODBC driver for one programming language which uses 64bit ints, therefore I'm sending everything as BIGINT. Shouldn't the SQL SERVER be able to just convert it automatically? AFAIK yes and since it works for 0-127, I don't think that that's the problem. And as I said, I also tried sending it as a string, which also worked but again only for 0-127.

Comment: MikeS, I'm sending the data as a signed `SQL_BIGINT`. The db column is simply `TINYINT`. `TINYINT UNSIGNED` can't be created.

Comment: Can you post the c++ code that you are using?

Comment: `SQLRETURN ret = SQLBindParameter(stmt, column, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SBIGINT, SQL_BIGINT, 19, 0, array, sizeof(int64), indArray);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was actually happening because as part of a test, I was "selecting" the inserted data back using `SQLFetch()` and `SQLGetData()`, and as target datatype used for the `SQLGetData()` function, I used `SQL_C_STINYINT` aka the signed version. Therefore the problem didn't happen when inserting the data but when I tried to "select" them back.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually already given, but not highlighted.

`TINYINT` is a one-byte *signed* integer. All values from Hex 00 to Hex 7F (or Bin 0000 0000 to 0111 1111, or Dec 0 to 127) are positive; all values from Hex 80 to Hex FF (or Bin 1000 0000 to 1111 1111 or Dec 128 to 255) are negative.

I'm afraid that for any signed integer greater than 127, you'll have to use a two-byte integer, `SMALLINT`.

And `SMALLINT` is supported by many more database platforms than `TINYINT` would be.

If you really want a single-byte integer, you'll have to cast your 64bit integer to `unsigned char` in C++, and put it into an `unsigned char` host variable.

But then you'll only see the "correct" value, if it's above 127, in your front end, and SELECT-ing from the database using any other tool, you'll see garbage.

Good luck - 
Marco the Sane

Comment: I'm not sure about this. According to the docs I posted a link to, it's 1-byte unsigned integer with range 0-255. `TINYINT UNSIGNED` cannot even be created with MSSQL. If I actually try to send a negative int, then it throws an error about arithmetic overflow, but that's not the point. Also, I don't really need it for myself, I'm just developing an ODBC module and wondering why SQL SERVER refuses values which should be valid according to docs.